# Spring Data JPA in CDI - ResourceLoader must not be null

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

After initial struggle getting the `EntityManager` produced using following  setup I ended up with `IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null` which I can't figure out. spring-data-jpa 2.1.1.RELESE, JBoss EAP 7.1. Am I missing something?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(ResourcePatternUtils.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.setResourceLoader(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.<init>(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:150)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.CustomRepositoryImplementationDetector.findCandidateBeanDefinitions(CustomRepositoryImplementationDetector.java:122)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.CustomRepositoryImplementationDetector.lambda$detectCustomImplementation$1(CustomRepositoryImplementationDetector.java:107)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.CustomRepositoryImplementationDetector.detectCustomImplementation(CustomRepositoryImplementationDetector.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.cdi.CdiRepositoryContext.getCustomImplementationClass(CdiRepositoryContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.cdi.CdiRepositoryBean.getCustomImplementationBean(CdiRepositoryBean.java:457)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.cdi.CdiRepositoryBean.getRepositoryFragments(CdiRepositoryBean.java:372)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.cdi.CdiRepositoryBean.create(CdiRepositoryBean.java:344)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryBean.create(JpaRepositoryBean.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.cdi.CdiRepositoryBean.create(CdiRepositoryBean.java:216)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
    at au.com.cba.reporting.db.JpaRepository$ReportingParameterRepository$845402535$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at au.com.cba.reporting.ReportingBean.findAll(ReportingBean.java:25)
...
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all"/>
```

Cdi Config

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CdiConfig {

    @Produces
    @Dependent
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "jdbc-tx")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="jdbc-tx" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/JDBC_TX_DATASOURCE</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Can you check into your custom repository have some method with Optional class. Might be that cause issue.

Comment: I did not know you can inject a CDI Bean in a Spring Bean

Comment: @Kukeltje the OP is not using Spring (the DI framework), just Spring Data JPA directly with CDI, which is supported by the Spring project (which is great!)

Comment: Ok, nice to know (not great ;-)). Using deltaspike data/jpa myself and omnipersistence

Comment: @Dhiren nope, it's a no-method-yet interface extending JpaRepository. No Optional anywhere close

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by a dependency version mismatch. All transitively pulled Spring libraries were version 5.1.1.RELEASE, only spring-core was 4.2.5.RELEASE for some reason.

Sorted out by introducing dependency management for the involved libraries and aligning them all to 5.1.1.RELEASE.